Is a function differentiable at a if we can't define either one of $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+}$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-}$
This question came in my test and I applied what I was told by my teacher.
The question is

If $f (x) = |1 – x|$, then the number of points where $g (x) = \arcsin(f(|x|))$ is non-differentiable, are

I found the domain of $g(x)$ to be $x\in [-2,2]$
After I plotted the graph and I found out that there were 3 non differentiable points ${-1,0,1}$. But the answer key said it was 5. I am assuming that it also counted ${-2,2}$.
So, here come my primary question.

Is a function differentiable at a if we can't define either one of $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+}$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-}$ ?

Does this question even make sense?
Because we can see that  $\lim\limits_{x \to 2^+} g(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to -2^-} g(x)$ are not defined in the function.

We don't check differentiability at boundry point so answer must be $3$. But some book define left differentiable and right differentiable too. In that case at $2$ and $-2$ it will be differentiable

@LeeMosher its inverse of sine function there

Oops, alright..

@mathophile can you provide some sources?

can you provide some sources? --- Did you try visiting your college/university library and looking up "differentiable" in the index of calculus and real analysis texts on the shelves? That seems to me the obvious way to answer a question like this. Plus, in doing this you will likely fortuitously stumble on other things of interest/use to you, such as a nice treatment of some topic you feel you need more review with or some interesting tidbit you had not been previously aware of.
